# Python Loop to generate multiple pivot tables from one pandas dataframe

Tags: python, loops, pivot-table, surveymonkey

I've selected a set of records from a larger data set that represents a specific organization. I need to iterate over this data and produce a pivot table that compares the demographic information to how that demographic answered the survey questions. There are 5 demographic questions, each with multiple choices for categorization. A pivot table provides a count of how each demographic category answered a survey question. I need to produce 5 pivot tables for each of the remaining 17 questions and store them to a dataframe. I'll stack the resulting dataframes later. The problem I'm having is trying to iterate over the main original dataframe, replacing the two column names for the crosstab. I can easily do one manually with the following code:

```
table18 = pd.pivot_table(org1_df, values='Business size?', index=['Business type?'], 
                              columns=['Survey Question 1'], 
                              aggfunc=['count'], fill_value=0)
```

Or

```
cross = pd.crosstab(org1_df["Business type?"], org1_df["Survey Question 2"])
cross
```

Here's the pivot table I was able to create:

The point is to determine how a small business answered the survey questions compared with a large business' answers. And so on for the other dozen+ categories we have on this survey.`

| Respondents | Business Type? | Business Size? | Survey Question 1 | Survey Question 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resp_1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| Resp_2 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

Sample data above.

I stored the demographic column names in a list:

```
column_names = ["Business type?", "Business size?"]
```

then added those to a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for name in column_names:
    d[name] = pd.DataFrame()
```

I tried a dictionary comprehension based on a similar question and answer:

```
dfs = {i[1]: pd.pivot_table(org1_df, index=i, values='Business type?', 
                            aggfunc='count', fill_value=0) for i, org1_df in zip(column_names, d)}
```

I received this error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'

I would greatly appreciate help on this task. As an aside, I'm not sure why when I leave values='Business type?' it doesn't matter for the resulting pivot table. The answers I'm getting matched what I get in Excel.

I'm working my way to a diverging stacked bar chart using matplotlib, but I have to get the data organized first.

UPDATE:  org1_df output
Based on the mock data above, I would produce 4 pivot tables from that.

1. Survey Question 1 - a count of the answers for "Business type?"
2. Survey Question 1 - a count of the answers for "Business size?"
3. Survey Question 2 - a count of the answers for "Business type?"
4. Survey Question 4 - a count of the answers for "Business size?"

Comment: Can you provide some data from `org1_df` please?. Try `print(org1_df.head(10))`

Comment: Please include the full error you're receiving.

Comment: I updated the post with the requested output. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's really important [not to post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15239951)

Comment: Barring pictures, which I've been warned not to do, I don't know how to get the output of org1_df.head(10) in here. It doesn't copy/paste well. I put in the data in a mock table above. That's the structure. I'm using Jupyter Notebook. Suggestions?

Comment: Update your question with the output of `print(org1_df.head(10).to_string())`. We need to reproduce the same error to understand the problem and find a solution.

Comment: @Corralien Thanks. I tried to paste the string output. It was one long run-on block of text. Formatting was terrible, so I took it back out.